# last inline list item disappears with appended list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have some php that creates an array from images in a folder:

```
    <?php
    $imagesDir = 'thumbnails/';
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    echo json_encode($images);
    ?>
```

Then some js that populates my page with these images:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON('imager.php', function(data) {        



 $('.wrap ol').empty();
 $.each(data, function() {
   $('.wrap ol').append('<li><div class="box"><div class="boxInner"><a href="'+this+'" class="thumbnail"><img src="'+this+'"/></a></div></div></li>');
 });


 });
 });
```

and it's working great, **however I already have a list item in this list that now diseappers from the DOM when the page loads:**

```
  <ol>
    <li>
     No images found
     </li>
        <!-- In-line js above right here --> 
    <li>
           <div class="commentBox2">
            <p>
           3 wolf moon freegan Odd Future Helvetica,
           Wes Anderson Pitchfork leggings polaroid biodiesel.
           Shoreditch 90's 8-bit, squid Vice biodiesel photo booth Godard fap lomo tousled quinoa.
           Farm-to-table street art fashion axe post-ironic tote bag pop-up quinoa, cardigan butcher asymmetrical.
           Kogi semiotics forage cray direct trade distillery. Selfies trust fund fanny pack messenger bag,
           fap ethical fingerstache Odd Future kale chips semiotics DIY twee Schlitz. Odd Future kogi American Apparel,
           chambray photo booth Austin brunch. Narwhal Echo Park gluten-free mixtape, Marfa tofu hashtag food truck
           squid fap freegan irony XOXO kale chips.
          </p>
           </div>

    </li>
  </ol>
```

On top of this, I have a script at the bottom of the of the body that resizes vertical images on `(window).load`, which is not firing (or at least no longer at the right time).

That JS looks like this:

```
           $(window).load(function() {
               $('img').each(function(index) {
                   var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
                   var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

                   // Check if the current width is larger than the max
                   if(height > width){
                       $(this).css("width", "44.5%"); // Set new width
                   }
               });
           });
```

Everything worked dandy when my images and their respective list items and containers were put directly in the HTML, but something is now amiss. Help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if more info is needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about removing `$('.wrap ol').empty();`? :)

Comment: Any thoughts on the last part with my other js not resizing the images any more?

Comment: No problem, can happen ;) Could you provide more code for your other issue?

Comment: I tried out the code and it's working fine. So you say the `(window).load` is not firing at all, right?

Comment: Anthony - It's working now. Not sure what was going on before.. It's worrisome that my code perhaps isn't strong enough to be consistent. hmm..

Comment: Yeah. So just refreshing a few times - sometimes my image resizes and sometimes it doesn't. I'm using a local test server so it gives me reason to worry. I wonder if the JS script runs before the images are loaded through the PHP and JSON, despite the fact that it's supposed to fire on `(window).load`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user2912472 Yeah, this might be the reason. You could try to put the resizing code right after the `$.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

> however I already have a list item in this list that now diseappers from the DOM when the page loads

That would because of this: `$('.wrap ol').empty();`, which empties the content of that ol tag.

As for your other problem, is your browser firing any JS errors? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Chrome Windows to open the debugger.

Comment: Nope, no errors :( The JS worked before I added the PHP and the JSON